# How to make GRASS and SAGA tools capable to use in QGIS？

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, saga

I installed QGIS, GRASS and GDAL by OSGeo4w package, and as I finish the installation, I want to use GRASS tool, I face this problem：

[image]

But I already installed GRASS and SAGA, how to make those tools in QGIS to be used？

Comment: Have you checked the files at C:\OSGeo4W\var\log to see that the setup ran without errors?

Comment: I have these errors：1. 2014/02/18 12:31:49 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory, 2. 2014/02/18 12:31:57 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2014/02/18 12:31:57 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/timestamp) failed 2 No such file or directory, 3. 2014/02/18 12:43:03 error: Environment variable 'PATH' length exceeds 1024; running with %WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\wbem

Comment: The last error has to be solved. You have to clean up your PATH variable. Have you got a GRASS icon on the desktop? In QGIS, `Processing -> Options -> Data Provider -> GRASS`, is it activated, and is the GRASS folder path correct?

Comment: 1. I found there are many things in my PATH variables, can I delete them at will？ And what should I do after I clean it up？ 2. In QGIS, GRASS is activated and the folder path is correct.

Comment: Apart from Windows entries, all you might experience is some other programmes may not run afterwards. Creating a recovery point might be a good idea. You have to reinstall QGIS after that to run the installer successfully to the end.

Comment: @AndreJoost Hello, thank you for your advice, I've cleaned up my path environment variables and reinstalled QGIS. I  have checked the log and it went fine with no error, but I still can't launch GRASS tools in QGIS interface(with the same Missing dependency window)

Comment: With QGIS 2.2 just around the cormer, I suggest to wait for that new version.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure the GRASS and SAGA folders in QGIS.
Follow these instructions from the QGIS documentation on [Configuring external applications](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html):

> The processing framework can be extended using additional
>   applications. Currently, SAGA, GRASS, OTB (Orfeo Toolbox) and R are
>   supported, along with some other command-line applications that
>   provide spatial data analysis functionalities. Algorithms relying on
>   an external application are managed by their own algorithm provider.